# Cannot add an item to a new DynamoDB table

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pycharm, amazon-dynamodb

I need to move an item from one DynamoDb table to another DynamoDB table.
When I use the `put_item ()` function I get an error:
`<class 'AttributeError'> Object 'dynamodb.ServiceResource' does not have attribute 'put_item'`

```
table = dynamodb.Table ('table1')
newTable = dynamodb.Table('table2')
```

It's the connection to my tables - the connection is successful
I read an item from Table 1 and put data in and sent it to the following function:

```
    try:
        dynamodb.put_item(newTable,data)
        return data
    except:
        e, p, t = sys.exc_info ()
        print ("test")
        print (e, p)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `dynamodb.put_item(newTable,data)` use:

`newTable.put_item(data)`

In your context, [put_item](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.put_item) is a method of `Table` object.

Comment: How did newTable.put_item() did "not work"? What error message did you get? Please refer to the put_item() documentation, this site is not a replacement to reading the documentation. Maybe it's just that you need to run `put_item(Item={...})`, not just `put_item({...})`.

Comment: I wrote it as you see in the first example-`def write_to_new_table(data):
    try:
        newTable.put_item (Item=data)` and the error I got is:<class 'botocore.exceptions.ClientError'> An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutItem operation: One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key PK_Hash  in the item

Comment: Based on this error message you reported -  "Missing the key PK_Hash in the item" - Can you make sure you're adding the item with the HashKey?